# Component not re-mounting when new props is passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I want to fetch data based on the name of the name of the doctor. On the 1st click on the Sales Overview tab, the component gets mounted and the data is fetched smoothly and I see all the charts get updated. However, when I use the Search button to fetch the data for a new doctor and then click on the Sales Overview tab, I don't see any fetch happening and I continue seeing the data of the previous MD.

Here is a screenshot of the search field and the tabs:

[image]

I'm passing the name of the doctor from the parent Search component to the SalesOverview1 child component like this:

```
  {
                            this.state.tab_button_clicked === 'sales_overview' && 
                            <SalesOverview1  
                                searchName = {this.state.searchName}
                            />
                            }
```

Inside SalesOverview1, I'm fetching the data in componentDidMount and then updating the various charts. I'm also setting the state of it based on the props received from parent Search component. I'm keeping a default value of ["[101]Anna"] if there is nothing to pass from search component to child SalesOverview1 comp.

```
  class SalesOverview1 extends Component {
    state = {
    page_id: 4,
    hcp_id: 101,
    sales_overview_data: [],
    searchName: this.props.searchName.length === 0 ? ["[101]Anna"] : this.props.searchName
}


 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Clicked on sales Overview!');
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let hcp_id = parseInt(this.state.searchName[0].replace(/(^.*\[|\].*$)/g, ''));
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id,
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            this.setState({ sales_overview_data: res.data });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

  render() {
       console.log('props data inside sales overview comp: ', this.props)
    console.log('state inside sales overview comp: ', this.state)

    return (
        <>
          <div class='row'>
                                                {
                                                    this.state.sales_overview_data.length !== 0 &&
                                                    <ChartBox
                                                        data={this.state.sales_overview_data[401]}
                                                    />
                                                }
            </div>
        </>
```

Basically, I want to run the api request after I receive a new props in this component. I want to re-mount so that I can make the api request.

In the api fetch, I'm using a replace function to extract the number between the square brackets which is then used for fetching data:

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any questions around the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a key while passing props to child component did the trick.

```
  {
                        this.state.tab_button_clicked === 'sales_overview' && 
                        <SalesOverview1  
                            key={this.state.finalsearchName}
                            searchName = {this.state.searchName}
                        />
                        }
```

I read that adding a key automatically re-mounts the child component if the props has changed.